# Vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-injection

I'm currently creating a Java application which uses MySQL.

I have read that in certain situations you should use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

By now I don't use prepared statements and I'm actually a bit worried that my Code might be vulnerable to SQL injection.

---

**Situations where MySQL queries are executed:**

- Direct query from inside the application(all variables used are defined in the application)
- API call (another application makes a MySQL query --> All variables used are defined inside the application which makes the call)

---

MySQL code:

```
    public static void Update(final String qry) {

        try {
            Statement stnt = connection.createStatement();
            stnt.executeUpdate(qry);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

---

```
public static ResultSet Query(String qry) {
    final ResultSet rs;

        try {
            Statement stnt = connection.createStatement();
            rs = stnt.executeQuery(qry);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return rs;
}
```

Comment: How do you construct your `qry` strings?

Comment: Why SQL Server tag here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on other factors, your application may remain vulnerable to SQL injection attack from someone with access to your application's environment.

For example, if the variables defined inside your code obtain their values from a configuration file, and later become part of SQL query, an attacker with access to your configuration files can execute a SQL injection attack by altering the content of your configuration file. Same goes for the other application: if there is a way to alter the content of the variables that go into the construction of your SQL query, it is likely possible to execute a successful SQL injection attack.

Using prepared statements provides catch-all defense against injection. The added complexity is well worth the trouble, though, because you plug a huge security hole with a relatively straightforward fix.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post an example of `String qry`?

In general, it could be vulnerable if you execute a query with values defined not inside the program but defined from outside.

For example:

If you have a `String name = null;` and `name` is user-defined and you push in the database that `name`, this could be potentially a vulnerability.

You could avoid injection with `preparedStatement` because you set parameters with methods that process the value to strings.

Example:

```
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USERNAME, JDBC_PASSWORD)){
    try (PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(
                                "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME
                                + "(id, date, ip, name) "
                                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?)")) {
    pst.clearParameters();

    pst.setInt(1, objectID);
    pst.setDate(2, (Date) objectDate);
    pst.setString(3, objectIP.getHostAddress());
    pst.setString(4, object.getName());

    int n = pst.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Inserted " + n + " rows.");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in insertion: " + e.getMessage());
    }
} catch (SQLException e){
    System.out.println("Problem with connection to db:" + e.getMessage());
}
```

With `TABLE_NAME` as a static string variable.

An SQL Injection attempted on the name, for example, would pass through `pst.setString`, so the DB will not see that as a query but simply as a value to insert in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which is your question, but yes, you might be vulnerable to sql injection, since you have scenarios in which query params are coming from outside your application (as you explain).

You might not be vulnerable anyway, if you are already doing checks when building your query string (or before) to prevent this scenario, even if you are not using prepared statements.

But i would strongly suggest to use prepared statements **with bind variables**